# BeautifulSoup miss some alphabets in decoding from utf-8 to unicode

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, encoding, utf-8, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse cyrillyc text from the site page and i have that error if i try to print soup.text of the scring which includes closing quotation marks in the word "word"

> **error** 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\xab' in position 6: charater maps to undefined

The original string page (utf-8)

```
urllib2.urlopen raw page = bbb = '\xab\x80\xd1\x8c\xc2\xbb'
```

\xbb and \xab- it's closing quotation mark

I try to convert to unicode by hand (BeautifulSoup does this too)
 `unicode(bbb, 'utf8', errors='ignore')`

But inspite of error key "ignore" unknown elements they still exists int

i get

> \xab\u0446\u0435\u0437\u0430\u0440\u044c**\xbb**'

I try to delete all unknown element starting with ^\x with help regular exp, but it's doesn't work

```
bbb = re.sub(r'[\x00-\x7f]', r' ', bbb)
```

Comment: The issue is not with bs4, it is an encoding issue on your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But inspite of error key "ignore" unknown elements they still exists

`u'\xbb'` is not an unknown element, there is no problem there. It represents the character U+00BB Right-Pointing Double Angle Quotation Mark. The Unicode string literals `u'\xbb'` and `u'\u00bb'` represent the same string.

`\x` has a different meaning depending on what kind of string literal it is used in. In a byte string, it introduces a hex-encoded byte from 0x00 to 0xFF. In a Unicode string, it introduces a hex-encoded character from U+0000 to U+00FF. When producing the `repr()` representation of a string, Python prefers to output characters in the range up to U+00FF using `\x` escapes rather than the arguably-clearer `\u` escapes, because they're shorter.

The `\u` and `\x` are merely alternative ways to refer to a character in the string literal representation; they are not literally part of the value of the string. There is no actual backslash in the value, so you can't use `re` to try to remove characters that might appear in the `repr()` form as backslash escapes.

The actual error:

> error 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\xab' in position 6: charater maps to undefined

Is just [PrintFails](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails) again as usual. Apparently your console is using an encoding that doesn't include the character U+00AB.

If you are using the Windows Command Prompt, you could try to use [win-unicode-console](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/win_unicode_console) as a workaround for the brokenness of that particular console.